# How to implement Transfer Learning by re-training partially a certain layer of an LSTM network?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, lstm, transfer-learning

I have an LSTM network consisting of two layers. I am trying to perform transfer learning by re-training partially the first layer of the network (re-training only some of the weights randomly from the first layer of the network). I loaded the weights of a previously trained LSTM model. I set the second layer to be untrainable. For the first layer, I want to re-train only a percentage of the weights (lets us say 10% of the weights only, chosen randomly from the first layer), and I want the rest of the weights in the first layer to be untrainable.

A part of the code is as follows. I am also not fully sure if `unit_index= i //4` needs to be considered.

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(NUM_IN_SEQUENCE,4), activation = "tanh", recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', return_sequences=True, use_bias=True))  
model.add(LSTM(6, input_shape=(NUM_IN_SEQUENCE,4), activation = "tanh", recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', return_sequences=True, use_bias=True))    
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))


earlystop=EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=3, verbose=0, mode='auto')
callbacks_list = [earlystop]

# load the previously trained weights
model.load_weights('rnn_model_2.h5')


# freeze the weights of the second layer
model.layers[1].trainable = False


# randomly select 10% of the units in the first layer to be trainable
total_units_layer_1 = model.layers[0].units
num_trainable_units_layer_1 = int(0.1 * total_units_layer_1)

# randomly select indices of units to be trainable
trainable_indices = np.random.choice(range(total_units_layer_1), size=num_trainable_units_layer_1, replace=False)

# assign the selected units trainable
for i, weight in enumerate(model.layers[0].trainable_weights):
    unit_index = i // 4  # each LSTM unit has 4 weights (input, recurrent, bias, and cell)
    if unit_index in trainable_indices:
        weight._trainable = True
    else:
        weight._trainable = False


# combile model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse','mae'])


callbacks = [
    EarlyStoppingByLossVal(monitor='val_loss', value=2e-6, verbose=1),
]


model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=64,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),callbacks=callbacks, verbose=1)
```